# How does one end up with a non-integer exponent in time complexity? (e.g., $O(n^{2.81})$)

Tags: complexity

Periodically I come across sentences like

"Winograd's variant [20] of this algorithm, whose asymptotic complexity is
also $O(n^{2.81})$ are considered" (from https://www.cise.ufl.edu/~sahni/papers/strassen.pdf)

I understand intuitively how we end up with complexities like $O(n^2)$ and $O(n \log n)$ because I can see how the loops and trees work.  But I've got no idea of how one ends up deriving a complexity with a decimal. Can someone give me an example how this happens?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The running time complexity of Strassen's algorithm is given by the recurrence
$$
T(n) = 7T(n/2) + O(n^2).
$$
(With a suitable base case.) The solution of this recurrence is $T(n) = O(n^{\log_2 7})$.

Strassen's algorithm multiplies two $n \times n$ matrices $A,B$ by decomposing them into four $(n/2)\times(n/2)$ matrices each, computing seven linear combinations of the smaller matrices each, say $(A_i,B_i)_{i=1,\dots,7}$, recursively computing $C_i = A_i B_i$, and computing the four $(n/2)\times(n/2)$ matrices of the result by taking linear combinations of the matrices $C_i$. That's how this running time came to be. If you want to learn more, there is a lot of information out there on Strassen's algorithm. There are, by the way, asymptotically faster algorithms for matrix multiplication, the current champion being [Le Gall](http://arxiv.org/abs/1401.7714).

Comment: I think I'm looking for the answer - 'you get a decimal, in this case, by solving this recurrence relation.' - I'm actualy trying to ask a slightly more general question about circumstances where this happens. Is a recurrence relation the only possible way that one would get a non-integer exponent?

Comment: There are other ways. For example, in network flow algorithms, some iterative algorithm might converge in $\sqrt{n}$ steps. Other examples are Chebyshev polynomials, which behave "like" polynomials of degree $d$ but have degree $\sqrt{d}$. There could be more examples, and in any case there is no reason for any list to be exhaustive – new ideas come up all the time.